# Criticize my proof that if $A\cap B = \emptyset $ then $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

My textbook claims its easy to prove $\phi$ (defined below) is a bijection ..... so I tried it. Call me stupid, but I didn't think it was so easy. Can anyone think of some simplifications, or ideas for shortening this proof (without sacrificing clarity or rigor)?

On a more general level, do you think that the proof (which is typical of my style) is too wordy? How is the level of detail?

[image]

Comment: I presume you mean $A \cap B = \phi$ ?

Comment: @SZN yes, thanks. In my defense \cup and \cap are like 5 pixels apart. Fixed.

Comment: Don't feel bad; when mathematicians say a proof is easy, they usually mean "straightforward and not requiring too much ingenuity", not necessarily "can be done in 2 lines and 5 seconds". Your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: I've posted a proof with fewer lines (though requiring a few more preliminary results). Otherwise I agree with Rahul. Your proof looks fine and the author was probably just expressing the fact that that *intuitively* the statement is clearly true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how rigorous your set theory course is. If $|A|$ denotes the order of $A$ *and* you assume $A$ and $B$ are finite the statement is obvious. Using "naïve" set theory I would write:

Since $A$ and $B$ are finite there are integers $n$ and $m$ corresponding to the order of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Furthermore, the order of $A\cup B$ must also be finite, since otherwise at least one of $A\cup B- B \subset A$ or $A\cup B -A \subset B$ would be infinite (an infinite set minus a finite set is again infinite) and an infinite set cannot be a subset of a finite one.

We can determine the order of $A \cup B$ by the following counting process. Set $x_A, x_B, y = 0$ and $S = A\cup B$. Choose some $a \in S$. Increment $x_A$ by one if $a \in A$ but not $B$, increment $x_B$ by one if $a \in B$ but not $A$, and increment $y$ by one if $x \in A \cap B$. Then put $S = S - \{a\}$, choose another member of $S$ and repeat. Since $A \cup B$ is finite, this process may only be continued for a finite number of steps until $S$ is empty and the counting process terminates. This means $x_A,x_B,y$ will also be finite at the completion of the process and so too will be $x_A + x_B +y = |A\cup B|$. Furthermore, the algorithm guarantees $x_A = |A|$, $x_B = |B|$ and $y = |A \cap B| = 0$, proving the claim.

Comment: I love the idea of using an algorithm. However, I've never taken a real course in set theory, and the proof is for a discrete math class. While I don't think such a proof would be acceptable in the class (since the point of the section is counting by finding bijections between sets), its good motivation to keep reading Halmos' book.

Comment: @EvanRosica if you have found Halmos' Naïve Set Theory book you are on the right track.